# using integers inside " " block in C

Tags: c

I am using system() func to use omxplayer in linux like `system("omxplayer /home/path/1.mp3');`, and I have many mp3 files named like `1.mp3` `2.mp3`. I am going to play these mp3 files randomly using rand() function. I am doing like;

```
switch(randnum)
{
    case 1:
        system("omxplayer /home/path/1.mp3");
    case 2: 
        system("omxplayer /home/path/2.mp3");
    ...
}
```

and I'm wondering that is it possible that doing like

```
system("omxplayer /home/path/randnum.mp3");
```

is this possible?

Comment: Investigate [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

Comment: Why not write a plugin for a plugin-capable player), use the random-button on a player (most have).

Comment: You are probably missing the `break` keyword at the end of each case.

Comment: @Olaf: This one, being specifically made for the Raspberry Pi, doesn't.

Comment: @DevSolar: Fair enough. Just had a look. That seems to be some rather simple video-player.

Comment: @Olaf: For a rather simple machine. What does any of this have to do with the OP's question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a random number:

```
int randomNum = (rand() % UPPER_LIMIT) + 1;
```

And then create and copy the required string into it using `sprintf()` or `snprintf()`:

```
char buffer[100];
sprintf(buffer, "omxplayer /home/path/%d.mp3", randomNum);
```

or

```
char buffer[100];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "omxplayer /home/path/%d.mp3", randomNum);
```

The difference between `sprintf()` and `snprintf()` is that `snprintf()`, unlike `sprintf()`, requires the size of the buffer as its second argument. This is done for preventing buffer overflows. Thus, **`snprintf()` is better than `sprintf()`** because of the extra security.

And finally, call `system()` with `buffer`:

```
system(buffer);
```

Comment: You should recommend `snprintf`, not `sprintf`.

Comment: You're still talking about `sprintf` like there's nothing wrong with it.  Please *only* recommend `snprintf`, unless you are prepared to explain why `sprintf` is dangerous and to be avoided.